# How can I get elements from nested lists?

Tags: python

The problem that I have to solve is;
write a recursive python function recSumList() that sums all the integer and float elements in the list. you can use the type() function to find the type of the element.
List : [1, "abcd", 2.2, [3.6, 4], [5, "8", 6]]

I just could write;

```
def recSumlist():
    list1 = [1, "abcd", 2.2, [3.6, 4], [5, "8", 6]]
```

I don't know how to get elements from nested lists and write this in recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

1. If current item is a `list`, get sum of all the elements.
2. Else if it is an `int` or `float` return the corresponding value.
3. If its `str` or something else return 0 to ignore the values

```
def recSumlist(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return sum(recSumlist(i) for i in l)
    return l if isinstance(l, (float, int)) else 0

print(recSumlist([1, "abcd", 2.2, [3.6, 4], [5, "8", 6]]))
```

**Output:**

```
21.8
```

---

As suggested by @chris, you can also further shorten it to this if you want -

```
def recSumlist(l):
    return sum(x if isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float) else recSumlist(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 0 for x in l)
```

Comment: You could also return: `sum(x if isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float) else recSumlist(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 0 for x in lst)`